# Filter out a specific string within a txt file

Tags: php, arrays, file, foreach

I have this search script:

```
    $search = $_GET["search"]; 
    $logfile = $_GET['logfile'];
    $file = fopen($logfile, "r");

?>
<head>
    <title>Searching: <?php echo $search ?></title>
</head>
<?php

    while( ($line =  fgets($file) )!= false) {
        if(stristr($line,$search)) {
            // case insensitive
            echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr><p>";                                
        }
    }
```

I want to filter out a specific string when searching for something in the txt file.

For example, the text file consists of this:

```
http://test.com/?id=2022458&pid=41&user=Ser_Manji
Ser_manji said "hello"
Ser_manju left the game
```

When you search for instance for "Ser_manji", I want to filter out this string:

```
http://test.com/?id=2022458&pid=41&user=Ser_Manji
```

But still display these two lines:

```
Ser_manji said "hello"
Ser_manju left the game
```

I hope this is possible, I myself tryied altering it so it wouldn't accept anything to do with lines that contained "test.com", but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Just get your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). And use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check if the search needle is in the line and if not display the line.

```
<?php

    $search = $_GET["search"]; 
    $logfile = $_GET['logfile'];
    $lines = file($logfile, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

?>

<head>
    <title>Searching: <?php echo $search ?></title>
</head>

<?php

    foreach($lines as $line) {
        if(strpos($line, $search) === FALSE) {
            echo "<font face='Arial'>$line</font><hr><p>";      
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am all new to working with this kind of PHP. But where does it allow me to specifically only filter "test.com" and just not show the whole line and show the rest which doesn't contain "test.com"

Comment: @Codah3 So you now want to display every line, but just remove certain text in the line? OR do you want to display the line only if a certain text is not found in  the line?

Comment: @Codah3 So where are we now with this question?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your if condition like so:

```
if (stristr($line, $search) && strpos($line,'test.com') === false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to filter out logs according to a specific username. This seems more complex than finding the right php function.

So you got your search q: `$search = $_GET['search']` which is a username.

You got your logs file: `$file = fopen($logfile, 'r')`.

Please note: You use GET parameters to get the filename but your example link `http://test.com/?id=2022458&pid=41&user=Ser_Manji` doesn't contain any `&logfile=logs.txt`. I suppose you know what you're doing.

Now if your logs structure is {username} {action} then we know that a "space" splits the username from his action. We can use explode: `$clues = explode(' ', $line);` and now `$username = $clues[0]` and `$action = clues[1]`.

So `if ($username == $search) echo $action`

Keep it simple and clean.

```
$search = $_GET["search"]; 
$logfile = $_GET['logfile'];
$file = fopen($logfile, "r");

while ($line = fgets($logfile)) {
    $clues = explode(' ', $line);
    $username = $clues[0];
    $action = $clues[1];
    if ($username == $search) {
        echo $action;
    }
}
```

You should test this by: `http://test.com?search=user_1234&logfile=logs.txt` if you are looking for user_1234 inside logs.txt file and so on..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match text (case insensitive) only at the beginning of the line, you could consider using a case insensitive and [anchored](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) regular expression, for filtering on a textfile ideally with the [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) function on array (e.g. via [`file`](http://php.net/file)) or with a *FilterIterator* on **SplFileObject**.

```
// regular expression pattern to match string at the 
// beginning of the line (^) case insensitive (i).
$pattern = sprintf('~^%s~i', preg_quote($search_term, '~'));
```

For the array variant:

```
$result = preg_grep($pattern, file($logfile));
foreach ($result as $line) {
    ... // $line is each grep'ed (found) line
}
```

With the iterators it's slightly different:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($logfile);
$filter = new RegexIterator($file, $pattern);
foreach ($filter as $line) {
    ... // $line is each filtered (found) line
}
```

The iterators give you a more object oriented approach, the array feels perhaps more straight forward. Both variants operate with the PCRE regular expressions in PHP which is the standard regular expression dialect in PHP.